# how to concatenate embedding layer in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, concatenation, pytorch, embedding

I am trying to concatenate embedding layer with other features. It doesn’t give me any error, but doesn’t do any training either. Is anything wrong with this model definition, how to debug this?

Note: The last column (feature) in my X is feature with word2ix (single word).
Note: The net works fine without the embedding feature/layer

originally posted on pytorch [forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-concatenate-embedding-layer/50553)

```py
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_features, h_sizes, num_words, embed_dim, out_size, dropout=None):
        super().__init__()


        self.num_layers = len(h_sizes)  # hidden + input


        self.embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(num_words, embed_dim)
        self.hidden = torch.nn.ModuleList()
        self.bnorm = torch.nn.ModuleList()
        if dropout is not None:
            self.dropout = torch.nn.ModuleList()
        else:
            self.dropout = None
        for k in range(len(h_sizes)):
            if k == 0:
                self.hidden.append(torch.nn.Linear(n_features, h_sizes[0]))
                self.bnorm.append(torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(h_sizes[0]))
                if self.dropout is not None:
                    self.dropout.append(torch.nn.Dropout(p=dropout))

            else:
                if k == 1:
                    input_dim = h_sizes[0] + embed_dim
                else:
                    input_dim = h_sizes[k-1]

                self.hidden.append(torch.nn.Linear(input_dim, h_sizes[k]))
                self.bnorm.append(torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(h_sizes[k]))
                if self.dropout is not None:
                    self.dropout.append(torch.nn.Dropout(p=dropout))

        # Output layer
        self.out = torch.nn.Linear(h_sizes[-1], out_size)

    def forward(self, inputs):

        # Feedforward

        for l in range(self.num_layers):
            if l == 0:
                x = self.hidden[l](inputs[:, :-1])
                x = self.bnorm[l](x)
                if self.dropout is not None:
                    x= self.dropout[l](x)

                embeds = self.embedding(inputs[:,-1])#.view((1, -1)
                x = torch.cat((embeds, x),dim=1)

            else:
                x = self.hidden[l](x)
                x = self.bnorm[l](x)
                if self.dropout is not None:
                    x = self.dropout[l](x)
            x = F.relu(x)
        output= self.out(x)

        return output
```

Comment: Are `inputs` of integer type or word (say `string`)? You can print the values last feature returns and check embeds (maybe `self.embedding` always returns placeholder value `0` in your case?). What does it mean no training? Loss does not change at all or is it divergent or hangs?

Comment: embedding gets integer index. I do word2ix and add that as last column to inputs.will try to update with small example.

Comment: Please add all relevant sections (e.g. `word2ix` function) and it's call. And yeah, MCVE would be great to have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were a few issues. The key one was data type. I mixed float features and int indices.

sample data and training before fix:

```py
NUM_TARGETS = 4
NUM_FEATURES = 3
NUM_TEXT_FEATURES = 1

x = np.random.rand(5, NUM_FEATURES)
y = np.random.rand(5, NUM_TARGETS)

word_ix = np.arange(5).reshape(-1,1).astype(int)
x_train = np.append(x, word_ix, axis=1)

x_train = torch.from_numpy(x).float().to(device)
y_train = torch.from_numpy(y).float().to(device)

h_sizes = [2,2]

net = Net(x_train.shape[1] , h_sizes=h_sizes, num_words=5, embed_dim=2, out_size=y_train.shape[1],dropout=.01)     # define the network
print(net)  # net architecture
net = net.float()
net.to(device)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.0001, weight_decay=.01)
loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()  # this is for regression mean squared loss

# one training loop
prediction = net(x_train)     # input x and predict based on x

loss = loss_func(prediction, y_train)     # must be (1. nn output, 2. target)

optimizer.zero_grad()   # clear gradients for next train
loss.backward()         # backpropagation, compute gradients
optimizer.step()        # apply gradients       
# train_losses.append(loss.detach().to('cpu').numpy())
```

To resolve this, I separated word index feature from x, and also removed `net.float()`.

changed the dtypes conversion to:

```py
x_train = torch.from_numpy(x).float().to(device)
y_train = torch.from_numpy(y).float().to(device) 

# NOTE: word index needs to be long
word_ix = torch.from_numpy(word_ix).to(torch.long).to(device)
```

and `forward` method changed to :

```py
    def forward(self, inputs, word_ix):

        # Feedforward

        for l in range(self.num_layers):
            if l == 0:
                x = self.hidden[l](inputs)
                x = self.bnorm[l](x)
                if self.dropout is not None:
                    x = self.dropout[l](x)

                embeds = self.embedding(word_ix)
                # NOTE:
                # embeds has a shape of (batch_size, 1, embed_dim)
                # inorder to merge this change this with x, reshape this to
                # (batch_size, embed_dim)
                embeds = embeds.view(embeds.shape[0], embeds.shape[2])
                x = torch.cat((x, embeds.view(x.shape)),dim=1)

            else:
                x = self.hidden[l](x)
                x = self.bnorm[l](x)
                if self.dropout is not None:
                    x = self.dropout[l](x)
            x = F.relu(x)
        output= self.out(x)

        return output
```